# What is the use of the vim screen in git bash?

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows

I'm learning to create websites. So far git bash has been my friend. 
But when committing, pushing or pulling the vim screen sometimes appears.
I do not want to use the vim screen and I use :wq to exit the vim screen.

[image: image of the vim screen]

I got at the vim screen when line:

```
$ git commit -a -m "added an extra parameter to habit 'caterory'"
```

was executed.

[image: screenshot of git bash]

**But What is the use of this vim screen?**

Comment: Note that Git allows you to *configure* any editor you prefer, using the `core.editor` setting. Whatever editor you choose must have certain text-file handling capabilities and be capable of waiting for you to *finish* editing a file, though, and `vim` does all that and is the editor many bash users prefer, so it's the default. If you prefer a Windows editor (e.g., atom), make sure you run it in a "wait for file to be saved back" mode.

Answer (score 1):

git pull is equivalent to git fetch + git merge and git merge requires a commit message in a non-fast-forward case. git opens an editor for you to enter the commit message.

You can avoid this behavior running

```
git pull --no-edit
```